# a working non-recursive floodfill algorithm written in C?

Tags: c, algorithm, flood-fill

I've been trying to find a working floodfill algorithm. Of the many algorithms I've tried only the 'recursive line fill' one behaves exactly as it should with the major caveat that it occasionally blows the stack. :(

I have tried many non-recursive implementations I've found and they have all been exceptionally tempermental: either they leave gaps in strange places, or flood the whole area (when they should be enclosed).

Anyone has a NON-recursive floodfill working sourcecode written in C (or c++ that isn't too heavily OOP and I can disentangle easily enough)?

Comment: Just a nit to pick: Algorithms are in pseudo code (and/or pictures), you are actually asking for an implementation (in C).

Comment: I once got this very question as part of a take-home programming interview, and I am guessing by your urgency that you did too.

Comment: actually, andy, no it's not for an interview :) it's for a graphics library i am writing :)

Comment: To answer the question: Yes, I have a non-recursive floodfilling implementation. It used a todo-list (and a done-list, IIRC).

Comment: Here is a video which demonstrates ,arching-floodfills, what happens if you march the previously recursive routine forwards in a X-Y loop: youtube.com/watch?v=LvacRISl99Y 
 write your own memory, a 2D array to record verified spaces, and onother array which records the complete filled image, and read and write to them using this loop system... it averages 20 instructions per pixel. i dealt with 2 billion voxel graphs at 5 million Voxels per second using above video logic.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Here's some C++ code that does what you want. It uses a queue, and is more efficient about insertions into the queue.

```
connectedRegion(const Point& source, RegionType& region, const Color target)
{
    Color src_color = color_of(source, region);
    if (region.count(source) == 0 || src_color == target)
        return;
    std::queue<Point> analyze_queue;
    analyze_queue.push(source);

    while (!analyze_queue.empty())
    {
        if (color_of(analyze_queue.front()) != src_color)
        {
            analyze_queue.pop();
            continue;
        }
        Point leftmost_pt = analyze_queue.front();
            leftmost_pt.col -= 1;
        analyze_queue.pop();
        Point rightmost_pt = leftmost_pt;
            rightmost_pt.col += 2;
        while (color_of(leftmost_pt, region) == src_color)
            --leftmost_pt.col;

        while (color_of(rightmost_pt, region) == src_color)
            ++rightmost_pt.col;

        bool check_above = true;
        bool check_below = true;
            Point pt = leftmost_pt;
            ++pt.col;
        for (; pt.col < rightmost_pt.col; ++pt.col)
        {
            set_color(pt, region, target);

            Point pt_above = pt;
                    --pt_above.row;
            if (check_above)
            {
                if (color_of(pt_above, region) == src_color)
                {
                    analyze_queue.push(pt_above);
                    check_above = false;
                }
            }
            else // !check_above
            {
                check_above = (color_of(pt_above, region) != src_color);
            }

            Point pt_below = pt;
                    ++pt_below.row;
            if (check_below)
            {
                if (color_of(pt_below, region) == src_color)
                {
                    analyze_queue.push(pt_below);
                    check_below = false;
                }
            }
            else // !check_below
            {
                check_below = (color_of(pt_below, region) != src_color);
            }
        } // for 
    } // while queue not empty
    return connected;
}
```

Comment: Hi banister, were you able to convert the above code in Objective C, i am kind of in the same situation and i am not sure if i can convert the above code in objective c, a little headstart will be helpful.

Comment: You can change the extension of an Objective-C file (.m) to be Objective-C++ (.mm) . You can then mix Obj-C and C++ in the same file. (You do not have to write your whole project in C++.)

Answer (score 28):

Just implement a stack of int pairs with an array of some fixed size (maybe the size of the image in pixels or the square root of that, for example) for the stack and track the top with an int.

Here is some C# code that implements floodfill non-recursively:

```
private static void Floodfill(byte[,] vals, Point q, byte SEED_COLOR, byte COLOR)
{
    int h = vals.GetLength(0);
    int w = vals.GetLength(1);

    if (q.Y < 0 || q.Y > h - 1 || q.X < 0 || q.X > w - 1)
        return;

    Stack<Point> stack = new Stack<Point>();
    stack.Push(q);
    while (stack.Count > 0)
    {
        Point p = stack.Pop();
        int x = p.X;
        int y = p.Y;
        if (y < 0 || y > h - 1 || x < 0 || x > w - 1)
            continue;
        byte val = vals[y, x];
        if (val == SEED_COLOR)
        {
            vals[y, x] = COLOR;
            stack.Push(new Point(x + 1, y));
            stack.Push(new Point(x - 1, y));
            stack.Push(new Point(x, y + 1));
            stack.Push(new Point(x, y - 1));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I've been suggesting this code to some friends. You now have three romhackers, myself included, using your code.

Comment: Very nice, this is the closest thing to a recursive one without the actual overflow problems

Comment: @Gerard: Nonsense; it only replaces one stack overflow problem with a different stack overflow problem.

Comment: @Brendan: Actually, if the Stack is implemented on the heap, then it is not a stack problem. In C++ maybe Stack<T> would be stack based, but in C# it is likely heap-based. Plus you could implement your own Stack<T> on the heap to be sure. (Admittedly it could do the book keeping in a more memory-efficient manner. Exercise for the reader.)

Comment: @JaredUpdike: A stack overflow is a stack problem (a problem caused by exceeding resource limits) regardless of how the stack is implemented or where it gets the resources.

Comment: This code does leave some gaps, especially on concave areas pointing to the right. A better method is scanfill, as implemented [here](https://simpledevcode.wordpress.com/2015/12/29/flood-fill-algorithm-using-c-net/) - but even that leaves a few gaps (but less than this algorithm).

Answer (score 10):

A quick googling brings up the [Wikipedia article on Flood Fill](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flood_fill) which includes pseudocode implementations which are not recursive. Below is some code that could help get you started, a basic queue implementation in C:

```
typedef struct queue_ { struct queue_ *next; } queue_t;
typedef struct ffnode_ { queue_t node; int x, y; } ffnode_t;

/* returns the new head of the queue after adding node to the queue */
queue_t* enqueue(queue_t *queue, queue_t *node) {
    if (node) {
        node->next = queue;
        return node;
    }
    return NULL;
}

/* returns the head of the queue and modifies queue to be the new head */
queue_t* dequeue(queue_t **queue) {
    if (queue) {
        queue_t *node = (*queue);
        (*queue) = node->next;
        node->next = NULL;
        return node;
    }
    return NULL;
}

ffnode_t* new_ffnode(int x, int y) {
    ffnode_t *node = (ffnode_t*)malloc(sizeof(ffnode_t));
    node->x = x; node->y = y;
    node->node.next = NULL;
    return node;
}

void flood_fill(image_t *image, int startx, int starty, 
                color_t target, color_t replacement) {
    queue_t *head = NULL;
    ffnode_t *node = NULL;

    if (!is_color(image, startx, starty, target)) return;

    node = new_ffnode(startx, starty);
    for ( ; node != NULL; node = (ffnode_t*)dequeue(&head)) {
        if (is_color(image, node->x, node->y, target)) {
            ffnode_t *west = node, *east = node;

            recolor(image, node->x, node->y, replacement);
            /* 1. move w to the west until the color of the node to the west
               no longer matches target */
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It's too bad that no one has an implementation of the fixed-memory flood fill algorithm mentioned in the Wikipedia entry on flood fill.  That would be cool. :)

Answer (score 7):

Isn't there a proof somewhere that all recursive functions can be implemented as an iterative function by using local data to mimic a stack? You could probably use std::vector to create stack-like behavior of the algorithm without blowing the stack since it will use the heap.

EDIT: I noticed you are using C, so instead of std::vector, you could just implement similar behavior via realloc as you need to add more elements to your local "stack" of whatever data structure you would use.

Comment: Well, he's not going to use std::vector in c, though.

Comment: Good point, I updated the answer with std::vector substitute advice.

Comment: Although it's possible to turn it into an iterative function with an explicit stack, I'd be worried that it might become a _very large_ stack - the maximum length being bounded by the longest acyclic path through the (rather dense) planar graph formed by the floodfill area. Using a breadth-first search strategy is likely to require less memory.

Comment: "Isn't there a proof somewhere that all recursive functions can be implemented as an iterative function by using local data to mimic a stack?" Yes, there is. It goes like this: All recursive algorithms are run by pushing a new frame on the call stack for every recursive call. Instead of doing that implicitly through function calls, you could do it explicitly yourself. QED. ;)

Comment: @Joren actually, in languages with tail call optimization, recursion is implemented without pushing a stack frame, but just replacing the parameters on the stack, using a fixed amount of memory. http://stackoverflow.com/a/33930/2543

Comment: @JaredUpdike That's true. I guess I could have said 'can be run' rather than 'are run', but the point stands.

Answer (score 7):

I do not know if my answer is perfectly relevant to the question you put, but hereafter I propose my C version of the Flood-Fill algorithm, which does not use recursive calls.

1-11-2017: NEW-VERSION; SUCCESFULLY TESTED WITH TWO BITMAPS.

It uses only a queue of the offsets of the new points, it works on the window: WinnOffs-(WinDimX,WinDimY) of the double-buffer: *VBuffer (copy of the screen or image) and, optionally, it write a mask of the flood-fill's result (*ExtraVBuff). 
ExtraVBuff must be filled it with 0 before the call (if you don't need a mask you may set ExtraVBuff= NULL); using it after call you can do gradient floodfill or other painting effects. NewFloodFill works with 32 Bit per Pixel and it is a C function. I've reinvented this algorithm in 1991 (I wrote his in Pascal), but now it works in C with 32 Bit per Pixel; also not uses any functions calls, does only a division after each "pop" from queue, and never overflows the queue, that, if it is sized in the right way (about 1/4 of the pixels of the image), it allows always to fill correctly any area; I show before the c-function (FFILL.C), after the test program (TEST.C):

```
#define IMAGE_WIDTH 1024
#define IMAGE_HEIGHT 768
#define IMAGE_SIZE IMAGE_WIDTH*IMAGE_HEIGHT
#define QUEUE_MAX IMAGE_SIZE/4

typedef int T_Queue[QUEUE_MAX];
typedef int T_Image[IMAGE_SIZE];

void NewFloodFill(int X,
                  int Y,
                  int Color,
                  int BuffDimX,
                  int WinOffS,
                  int WinDimX,
                  int WinDimY,
                  T_Image VBuffer,
                  T_Image ExtraVBuff,
                  T_Queue MyQueue)

/* Replaces all pixels adjacent to the first pixel and equal to this;   */
/* if ExtraVBuff == NULL writes to *VBuffer (eg BUFFER of 786432 Pixel),*/
/* otherwise prepare a mask by writing on *ExtraVBuff (such BUFFER must */
/* always have the same size as *VBuffer (it must be initialized to 0)).*/

/*         X,Y: Point coordinates' of origin of the flood-fill.         */
/*     WinOffS: Writing start offset on *VBuffer and *ExtraVBuff.       */
/*    BuffDimX: Width, in number of Pixel (int), of each buffer.        */
/*     WinDimX: Width, in number of Pixel (int), of the window.         */
/*       Color: New color that replace all_Pixel == origin's_point.     */
/*     WinDimY: Height, in number of Pixel (int), of the window.        */
/*     VBuffer: Pointer to the primary buffer.                          */
/*  ExtraVBuff: Pointer to the mask buffer (can be = NULL).             */
/*     MyQueue: Pointer to the queue, containing the new-points' offsets*/

{
 int VBuffCurrOffs=WinOffS+X+Y*BuffDimX;
 int PixelIn=VBuffer[VBuffCurrOffs];
 int QueuePnt=0;
 int *TempAddr=((ExtraVBuff) ? ExtraVBuff : VBuffer);
 int TempOffs1;
 int TempX1;
 int TempX2;
 char FLAG;

 if (0<=X && X<WinDimX && 0<=Y && Y<WinDimY) do
  {
   /* Fill to left the current line */
   TempX2=X;
   while (X>=0 && PixelIn==VBuffer[VBuffCurrOffs])
    {
     TempAddr[VBuffCurrOffs--]=Color;
     --X;
    }
   TempOffs1=VBuffCurrOffs+1;
   TempX1=X+1;

   /* Fill to right the current line */
   VBuffCurrOffs+=TempX2-X;
   X=TempX2;
   while (X+1<WinDimX && PixelIn==VBuffer[VBuffCurrOffs+1])
    {
     ++X;
     TempAddr[++VBuffCurrOffs]=Color;
    }
   TempX2=X;

   /* Backward scan of the previous line; puts new points offset in Queue[] */
   if (Y>0)
    {
     FLAG=1;
     VBuffCurrOffs-=BuffDimX;
     while (X-->=TempX1)
      {
       if (PixelIn!=VBuffer[VBuffCurrOffs] ||
           ExtraVBuff && Color==ExtraVBuff[VBuffCurrOffs])
        FLAG=1;
       else
       if (FLAG)
        {
         FLAG=0;
         if (QueuePnt<QUEUE_MAX)
          MyQueue[QueuePnt++]=VBuffCurrOffs;
        } 
       --VBuffCurrOffs;
      }
    }

   /* Forward scan of the next line; puts new points offset in Queue[] */
   if (Y<WinDimY-1)
    {
     FLAG=1;
     VBuffCurrOffs=TempOffs1+BuffDimX;
     X=TempX1;
     while (X++<=TempX2)
      {
       if (PixelIn!=VBuffer[VBuffCurrOffs] ||
           ExtraVBuff && Color==ExtraVBuff[VBuffCurrOffs])
        FLAG=1;
       else
       if (FLAG)
        {
         FLAG=0;
         if (QueuePnt<QUEUE_MAX)
          MyQueue[QueuePnt++]=VBuffCurrOffs;
        }
       ++VBuffCurrOffs;
      }
    }

   /* Gets a new point offset from Queue[] */ 
   if (--QueuePnt>=0)
    {
     VBuffCurrOffs=MyQueue[QueuePnt];
     TempOffs1=VBuffCurrOffs-WinOffS;
     X=TempOffs1%BuffDimX;
     Y=TempOffs1/BuffDimX;
    }

  /* Repeat the main cycle until the Queue[] is not empty */
  } while (QueuePnt>=0);
}
```

Here there is the test program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <malloc.h>
#include "ffill.c"

#define RED_COL 0xFFFF0000
#define WIN_LEFT 52
#define WIN_TOP 48
#define WIN_WIDTH 920
#define WIN_HEIGHT 672
#define START_LEFT 0
#define START_TOP 671

#define BMP_HEADER_SIZE 54

typedef char T_Image_Header[BMP_HEADER_SIZE];
void main(void)
{

 T_Image_Header bmpheader;
 T_Image *image;
 T_Image *mask;
 T_Queue *MyQueue;

 FILE *stream;
 char *filename1="ffill1.bmp";
 char *filename2="ffill2.bmp";
 char *filename3="ffill3.bmp";
 int bwritten;
 int bread;

 image=malloc(sizeof(*image));
 mask=malloc(sizeof(*mask));
 MyQueue=malloc(sizeof(*MyQueue));

 stream=fopen(filename1,"rb");
 bread=fread(&bmpheader, 1, BMP_HEADER_SIZE, stream);
 bread=fread((char *)image, 1, IMAGE_SIZE<<2, stream);
 fclose(stream);

 memset(mask,0,IMAGE_SIZE<<2);

 NewFloodFill(START_LEFT,
              START_TOP,
              RED_COL,
              IMAGE_WIDTH,
              IMAGE_WIDTH*WIN_TOP+WIN_LEFT,
              WIN_WIDTH,
              WIN_HEIGHT,
              *image,
              NULL,
              *MyQueue);

 stream=fopen(filename2,"wb+");
 bwritten=fwrite(&bmpheader, 1, BMP_HEADER_SIZE, stream);
 bwritten=fwrite((char *)image, 1, IMAGE_SIZE<<2, stream);
 fclose(stream);

 stream=fopen(filename3,"wb+");
 bwritten=fwrite(&bmpheader, 1, BMP_HEADER_SIZE, stream);
 bwritten=fwrite((char *)mask, 1, IMAGE_SIZE<<2, stream);
 fclose(stream);

 free(MyQueue);
 free(mask);
 free(image);
}
```

I've used, for the input of the test program shown, the follow Windows uncompressed .BMP image (ffill1.bmp):

[image]

Filled, by the test program shown, as follows (ffill2.bmp):

[image]

Using "mask" instead of NULL, the output bitmap is (ffill3.bmp):

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You can convert any recursive algorithm to iterative by creating an explicit stack or queue  and loading work onto it/pulling it off.

All you need is to choose a nice, compact representation of the work to be done. Worst case: create a `struct` holding the arguments you would normally pass to the recursive version...

Answer (score 2):

We noticed that our floodfill implementation on 3d volumes was consuming way much memory; so we modified the code in the following ways (there was a vast improvement):

1. Create a sphere of radius = 10 voxs around the starting point, and mark all the voxels within that radius as "to be visited"
2. If the current voxel > threshold, insert 1.
3. Go to the neighbors [+1, -1, 0] (also check that one doesn't revisit any voxel), if the neighbor.getVoxVal = 0 (the initialization value for the target volume), then it falls at the boundary of the sphere, insert the coordinates in a different stack. (this would be the starting point for our next sphere)
4. radius = radius + 10 (voxels)

So at a time, our floodfill is working on a concentric sphere and filling things up, which is a part of the entire volume, and as I said, this has reduced the memory consumption drastically, but I am still searching for an implementation/idea that would be better.

Answer (score 1):

I have a non-recursive flood fill, but I won't post it because it's the solution to a homework assignment.  But here's a hint: depth-first search, which is the natural algorithm, uses *far* more auxiliary space than a breadth-first search.  Here's what I wrote at the time (suitably expurgated):

> I dare not try depth-first search by simple recursion; the depth of recursion is limited only by REDACTED, and my experiments show that an PROBLEM REDACTED could nevertheless require a stack depth of over a million.  So I put the stack in an auxiliary data structure.  Using an explicit stack actually makes it easy to try breadth-first search as well, and it turns out that breadth-first search can use forty times less space than depth-first search.

For my data structure I used the `Seq_T` from Dave Hanson's [C Interfaces and Implementations](http://www.cs.princeton.edu/software/cii/); changing from depth-first to breadth-first requires changing just one function call.

Comment: Err, you need to fix up your second sentence which compares the auxiliary space of the same algorithms. :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can quickly convert a recursive flood fill into an ultra-performant pseudo-recursive... Don't edit the lines,just add new lines:
place the recursive function in an XY loop for added structure.
record the found neighbors to a "found neighbors array"
instead of memory, so you will start packing the 4-16-64 style tree of the recursion into an XY array. memory usage goes from 1 gygabyte to 2 megabytes.
Also use a 2D array called "filled neighbors array"... abort the function for any pixels marked as filled in the "filled neighbors array", this uses 2 instructions for every duplicate, 20 instructions for every floodfill operation, and it iteratively fills leftwards and upwards like dominoes, insanely quickly.

1024x1024 uses about 1million *20 instructions which is 0.1 seconds for a single core.

I achieve 9 million filled pixels per second on an i7 in this way, i have a video as proof, and a blog page with code and theory explanations:

[www.youtube.com/watch?v=4hQ1wA4Sl4c](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4hQ1wA4Sl4c)

and here is a page where I attempted to explain how it works. 
http://unity3dmc.blogspot.com/2017/02/ultimate-3d-floodfill-scanline.html?m=1

And the code.

Recursions would be the fastest if they could stay organized.

If you recurse through a grid of data (image) you can store the processing of the recursions in grid format too, because the processed steps represent pixels from the grid, rather than explode the results into a tree format.

Answer (score 1):

I found this fill by Paul Heckbert to be the simplest non-recursive C implementation:

```
/*
 * A Seed Fill Algorithm
 * by Paul Heckbert
 * from "Graphics Gems", Academic Press, 1990
 *
 * user provides pixelread() and pixelwrite() routines
 */

/*
 * fill.c : simple seed fill program
 * Calls pixelread() to read pixels, pixelwrite() to write pixels.
 *
 * Paul Heckbert    13 Sept 1982, 28 Jan 1987
 */

typedef struct {        /* window: a discrete 2-D rectangle */
    int x0, y0;         /* xmin and ymin */
    int x1, y1;         /* xmax and ymax (inclusive) */
} Window;

typedef int Pixel;      /* 1-channel frame buffer assumed */

Pixel pixelread(int x, int y);
void pixelwrite(int x, int y, Pixel p);

typedef struct {short y, xl, xr, dy;} Segment;
/*
 * Filled horizontal segment of scanline y for xl<=x<=xr.
 * Parent segment was on line y-dy.  dy=1 or -1
 */

#define MAX 10000       /* max depth of stack */

#define PUSH(Y, XL, XR, DY) /* push new segment on stack */ \
    if (sp<stack+MAX && Y+(DY)>=win->y0 && Y+(DY)<=win->y1) \
    {sp->y = Y; sp->xl = XL; sp->xr = XR; sp->dy = DY; sp++;}

#define POP(Y, XL, XR, DY)  /* pop segment off stack */ \
    {sp--; Y = sp->y+(DY = sp->dy); XL = sp->xl; XR = sp->xr;}

/*
 * fill: set the pixel at (x,y) and all of its 4-connected neighbors
 * with the same pixel value to the new pixel value nv.
 * A 4-connected neighbor is a pixel above, below, left, or right of a pixel.
 */

void fill(x, y, win, nv)
int x, y;   /* seed point */
Window *win;    /* screen window */
Pixel nv;   /* new pixel value */
{
    int l, x1, x2, dy;
    Pixel ov;   /* old pixel value */
    Segment stack[MAX], *sp = stack;    /* stack of filled segments */

    ov = pixelread(x, y);       /* read pv at seed point */
    if (ov==nv || x<win->x0 || x>win->x1 || y<win->y0 || y>win->y1) return;
    PUSH(y, x, x, 1);           /* needed in some cases */
    PUSH(y+1, x, x, -1);        /* seed segment (popped 1st) */

    while (sp>stack) {
    /* pop segment off stack and fill a neighboring scan line */
    POP(y, x1, x2, dy);
    /*
     * segment of scan line y-dy for x1<=x<=x2 was previously filled,
     * now explore adjacent pixels in scan line y
     */
    for (x=x1; x>=win->x0 && pixelread(x, y)==ov; x--)
        pixelwrite(x, y, nv);
    if (x>=x1) goto skip;
    l = x+1;
    if (l<x1) PUSH(y, l, x1-1, -dy);        /* leak on left? */
    x = x1+1;
    do {
        for (; x<=win->x1 && pixelread(x, y)==ov; x++)
        pixelwrite(x, y, nv);
        PUSH(y, l, x-1, dy);
        if (x>x2+1) PUSH(y, x2+1, x-1, -dy);    /* leak on right? */
skip:       for (x++; x<=x2 && pixelread(x, y)!=ov; x++);
        l = x;
    } while (x<=x2);
    }
}
```

source: https://github.com/erich666/GraphicsGems/blob/master/gems/SeedFill.c

Answer (score 1):

I made a simple implementation in C.

Context in my example:

```c
#define EMPTY    ' '
#define REVEALED '-'

#define GRID_SET(P, X) (grid[W * (P).y + (P).x] = (X))

typedef struct {
    int x, y;
} vec2_t;

char grid[H * W] = "##########"
                   "##########"
                   "##   #####"
                   "##    ####"
                   "#      ###"
                   "#        #"
                   "#       ##"
                   "##     ###"
                   "##########"
                   "##########";

static bool is_empty(vec2_t p) {
    return p.x >= 0 && p.x < W && p.y >= 0 && p.y < H &&
           grid[W * p.y + p.x] == EMPTY;
}
```

Queue functions:

```c
static vec2_t queue_pop_front(vec2_t* q, int* top) {
    vec2_t ret = q[0];

    /* Shift. Note that `top` is not the last pushed value, but the next one */
    *top -= 1;
    for (int i = 0; i < *top; i++)
        q[i] = q[i + 1];

    return ret;
}

static void queue_push(vec2_t* q, int* top, vec2_t x) {
    q[*top] = x;
    *top += 1;
}
```

Flood fill:

```c
static void flood_fill(vec2_t p) {
    /* First in, first out */
    vec2_t* queue = malloc(W * H * sizeof(vec2_t));
    int queue_pos = 0;

    /* Push parameter and reveal it */
    queue_push(queue, &queue_pos, p);
    GRID_SET(p, REVEALED);

    /* Queue is not empty */
    while (queue_pos > 0) {
        const vec2_t cur = queue_pop_front(queue, &queue_pos);

        vec2_t up = { cur.x, cur.y - 1 };
        if (is_empty(up)) {
            queue_push(queue, &queue_pos, up);
            GRID_SET(up, REVEALED);
        }

        vec2_t down = { cur.x, cur.y + 1 };
        if (is_empty(down)) {
            queue_push(queue, &queue_pos, down);
            GRID_SET(down, REVEALED);
        }

        vec2_t left = { cur.x - 1, cur.y };
        if (is_empty(left)) {
            queue_push(queue, &queue_pos, left);
            GRID_SET(left, REVEALED);
        }

        vec2_t right = { cur.x + 1, cur.y };
        if (is_empty(right)) {
            queue_push(queue, &queue_pos, right);
            GRID_SET(right, REVEALED);
        }
    }

    free(queue);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Below is my BFS based iterative c++ method for the flood fill problem:

```
// M is the input matrix, with every entry(pixel) have a color
// represented with an integer value.
// (x, y) row and column of seed point respectively
// k: The new color to fill the seed and its adjacent pixels
void floodFill(vector<vector<int>> &M, int x, int y, int k) {
    queue<pair<int, int>> nodeQ;
    nodeQ.push({x, y});
    int oldCol = M[x][y];
    while(!nodeQ.empty()) {
        pair<int, int> currNode = nodeQ.front();
        nodeQ.pop();
        if(M[currNode.first][currNode.second] == oldCol) {
            M[currNode.first][currNode.second] = k;
            if(currNode.first > 0) nodeQ.push({currNode.first-1, currNode.second});
            if(currNode.first < (M.size()-1)) nodeQ.push({currNode.first+1, currNode.second});
            if(currNode.second > 0) nodeQ.push({currNode.first, currNode.second-1});
            if(currNode.second < (M[0].size()-1)) nodeQ.push({currNode.first, currNode.second+1});
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a guide for a non-recursive routine which completes 10 million pixels per second: [it's called marching-floodfills](http://youtube.com/watch?v=LvacRISl99Y), what happens if you march the previously recursive routine forwards in a X-Y loop.

write your own memory, a 2D array to record verified spaces, and another array which records the complete filled image, and read and write to them using this loop system... it averages 20 instructions per pixel. i dealt with 2 billion voxel graphs at 5 million Voxels per second using above video logic.