# Android Drawing Fill Tool

Tags: android, android-canvas, android-view

I am making a drawing app for android and I need some help adding a fill tool.

I want the tool to flood fill, and to behave like it would in Microsoft Paint, but on a phone.

I have a custom view that draws a path on a canvas. I draw different paths for different pens and brushes, and I allow users to pick line thickness and color.

When I do:

```
paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
```

and I paint, I don't get a fill how I want.

I have gotten some suggestions to use the "Flood Fill Algorithm", but I can't figure out how to implement it in my code.

Where could I go to see an example of what I am trying to do? Does anyone have sample code to show me how I could make the tool work with my android view?

**EDIT:**

CartoonView.java:

```
    public class CartoonView extends View {
        ArrayList<Paint> paints = new ArrayList<Paint>();
        ArrayList<Path> paths = new ArrayList<Path>();
        int color;
        int thickness;
        boolean pencilSelected;

    public boolean isPencilSelected() {
        return pencilSelected;
    }

    public void setPencilSelected(boolean pencilSelected) {
        this.pencilSelected = pencilSelected;
    }

    public ArrayList<Paint> getPaints() {
        return paints;
    }

    public void setPaints(ArrayList<Paint> paints) {
        this.paints = paints;
    }

    public ArrayList<Path> getPaths() {
        return paths;
    }

    public void setPaths(ArrayList<Path> paths) {
        this.paths = paths;
    }

    public int getThickness() {
        return thickness;
    }

    public int getColor() {
        return color;
    }

    public CartoonView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        color = Color.BLACK;
        thickness = 3;
        pencilSelected = true;
        createPaint();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        for (Path path : paths) {
            canvas.drawPath(path, paints.get(paths.indexOf(path)));
        }
    }

    public void setPaintColor(int newColor) {
        color = newColor;
        createPaint();
    }

    public void setPaintThickness(int newThickness) {
        thickness = newThickness;
        createPaint();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        if (this.isEnabled()) {
            Path path;
            if (paths.size() == 0) {
                path = new Path();

                Paint paint = new Paint();
                paint.setAntiAlias(true);
                paint.setStrokeWidth(5f);
                paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
                paint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
                paint.setColor(color);
                paint.setStrokeWidth(thickness);

                thickness = (int) paint.getStrokeWidth();

                paths.add(path);
                paints.add(paint);
            } else {
                path = paths.get(paths.size() - 1);
            }
            float eventX = event.getX();
            float eventY = event.getY();
            switch (event.getAction()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                path.moveTo(eventX, eventY);
                return true;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                path.lineTo(eventX, eventY);
                break;
            default:
                return true;
            }
            invalidate();
        }
        return true;
    }

    public void createPaint() {
        Path path = new Path();

        Paint paint = new Paint();
        paint.setAntiAlias(true);
        paint.setStrokeWidth(5f);
        paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        paint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
        paint.setColor(color);
        paint.setStrokeWidth(thickness);

        paths.add(path);
        paints.add(paint);
    }

    public void clearView(){
        paths.clear();
        paints.clear();
        invalidate();
    }
}
```

Comment: fill a closed area with a color?

Comment: use flood fill algorithm

Comment: @Raghunandan could I have some sample code please?

Comment: @Raghunandan I cannot seem to get this to work

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flood_fill

Comment: @JohnyTex could you supply some sample code as to how I could implement this in my app?

Comment: please show the code you have so far - how to implement flood fill depends on your data-structures

Comment: I think this answer could help: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16968484/1606534

Comment: @ana01 I will check it out

Comment: @ligi I added my code.

Comment: @user3771655 as you basically have no data-structure - this would need some serious coding ( means >5min ) - I do not have this time spare at the moment - not even for 150rep - good luck anyway!

Comment: @ligi is there a time you could still help, maybe later? thanks

Comment: @user3771655 sorry, but not without you doing more work your own - please read http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flood_fill - try to understand it and ask specific questions - not too broad ones as this one

Comment: http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android-sdk-drawing-with-pattern-fills--mobile-19527 try this..
here pattern is used ,,,u may remove pattern and use as u want

Comment: @Vaishali thanks, let me check that out

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I completely agree with the some of the commentators who said about Flood Fill Algorithm.

Below is the function which works as what you want. Just try it:

```
private void FloodFill(Bitmap bmp, Point pt, int targetColor, int replacementColor){
Queue<Point> q = new LinkedList<Point>();
q.add(pt);
while (q.size() > 0) {
    Point n = q.poll();
    if (bmp.getPixel(n.x, n.y) != targetColor)
        continue;

    Point w = n, e = new Point(n.x + 1, n.y);
    while ((w.x > 0) && (bmp.getPixel(w.x, w.y) == targetColor)) {
        bmp.setPixel(w.x, w.y, replacementColor);
        if ((w.y > 0) && (bmp.getPixel(w.x, w.y - 1) == targetColor))
            q.add(new Point(w.x, w.y - 1));
        if ((w.y < bmp.getHeight() - 1)
                && (bmp.getPixel(w.x, w.y + 1) == targetColor))
            q.add(new Point(w.x, w.y + 1));
        w.x--;
    }
    while ((e.x < bmp.getWidth() - 1)
            && (bmp.getPixel(e.x, e.y) == targetColor)) {
        bmp.setPixel(e.x, e.y, replacementColor);

        if ((e.y > 0) && (bmp.getPixel(e.x, e.y - 1) == targetColor))
            q.add(new Point(e.x, e.y - 1));
        if ((e.y < bmp.getHeight() - 1)
                && (bmp.getPixel(e.x, e.y + 1) == targetColor))
            q.add(new Point(e.x, e.y + 1));
        e.x++;
    }
}}
```

You can also read some information regarding Flood fill on link: [Link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8070401/android-flood-fill-algorithm), [Link2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flood_fill) and [Link3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9748206/android-how-to-do-this-framing-paint)

Hope you got answer to your question. Please let me know i can help you in another way or you have doubt in above answer.

Enjoy Coding... :)

**Updated with more information:**

Above functiona will work on bases of the FloodFill algorithm. What it will exactly do is,
It will detect the pixcel point and color on that pixel whereever you touch.
Then it will fill the color by pixel to pixel by the selected color till any pixel dont have different color then it have currently.

I hope it will help you.

Comment: thanks so much for the answer, could you tell me what parameters should be passed in the function?

Comment: @user3771655 what o you mean by path? is it related to the paint you have done with path and then fill color in it?

Comment: @user3771655 the parameters are self explained. 1) Bitmap: that you want to fill with color 2)Point: that you touch to fill color 3)Target color: that you want to fill color in touch place and around it.(e.g.: blue) 4)replace color : that you want to replace to. (e.g.: red)

Comment: Do you want to change the color by touching on the drawing line? or want to fill color with in the particular area?

Comment: @I want to be able to fill an area with color

Comment: So I would convert my view into a bitmap, take the point that was touched, use the FloodFill function you gave me to fill in the bitmap, then draw the bitmap again over my view?

Comment: @user3771655 yes that's the one of the way you can have the effect you want.

Comment: I am wondering what some of the other ways I can flood fill my view, since you said that's one of the ways. Thank you

Comment: please give me an answer.

Comment: Sorry but i don't have other idea to make that. Flood fill is the best one till now to have the effect you want. So please go with that.

Answer (score 0):

```
private void setupDrawing(){

        drawPath = new Path();
        drawPaint = new Paint();
        drawPaint.setColor(paintColor);
        drawPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
        drawPaint.setStrokeWidth(50);
        drawPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);

     // here i use round round u may use anther option also :) 

        drawPaint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
        drawPaint.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);
        canvasPaint = new Paint(Paint.DITHER_FLAG);
 }
```

Comment: or u may refere  this link http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android-sdk-drawing-with-pattern-fills--mobile-19527

Comment: thanks for the answer! When I use this I get the same type of fill as paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL); for the canvas paint

Comment: also, the link is about drawing patterns, I need tro be able to click and fill an empty space/