# Ubuntu14.04 gets stuck in a login loop

Tags: ubuntu, authentication, desktop, chmod

My Ubuntu14.04 gets stuck in a login loop. i can auto login to desktop  as root,but other user gets stuck in a login loop.

(It is a dual-boot system ,windows 7 and Ubuntu14.04)

One day i `chmod -R 777 /usr/lib`,then i found sudo couldn't use anymore,so i enter recovery mode to fixed the problem

```
  mount -o remount,rw /
  sudo chmod 0755 /usr/lib
  chmod 4755 /usr/lib/sudo/sudoers.so
```

Then i found i could not login in anymore. 
  i add a new file  `/etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf`
  the content is:

```
  [SeatDefaults]
  autologin-user=root
```

reboot, i could autologin as root, and could see the default desktop,but when i try to login in as other user ,i just get stuck in a login loop in the login step.

I try to add a new  user, still get stuck in a login loop(but i can login in terminal ,also ,i can still use windows system)

i found a web page which might solve my problem ,https://askubuntu.com/questions/223501/ubuntu-gets-stuck-in-a-login-loop#,
  but  i try most of it , it didnt work for me :

```
  1. i try to install/reinstall lightdm and gdm,failed,
  2. i try to install  Nvidia and AMD/ATI graphics driver,  
  'sudo apt-get install nvidia-390' and 'sudo apt-get install fglrx',
  both failed because 'lib32gcc1 : Depends: gcc-4.9-base (= 4.9-20140406-0ubuntu1) but 4.9.3-0ubuntu1 is to be installed',
  I  try to install gcc-4.9-base,it shows too many dependence have to install/update 
  3. sudo apt-get -y install lubuntu-desktop and sudo apt-get -y install lxdm still get login loop
  4. chmod for Xauthority /tmp
```

how can i solve it? Thanks!

ps : There is another clue, the `/var/log/cups/error_log` grow rapidly ,
  the message is

```
  W [01/Aug/2018:00:38:14 +0800] Notifier for subscription 1 (dbus://) went away, retrying!
  E [01/Aug/2018:00:38:14 +0800] Directory "/usr/lib/cups/notifier" has insecure permissions (044755/uid=0/gid=0).
```

and i see memory usage grow too , but could not see witch process use it,why  cupsd use 90+% cpu?

```
Tasks: 186 total,   2 running, 184 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
%Cpu(s):  9.4 us, 16.0 sy,  0.0 ni, 74.3 id,  0.3 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.0 st
KiB Mem:  12183948 total, 12031564 used,   152384 free,     3780 buffers
KiB Swap:  4071420 total,     8456 used,  4062964 free. 10761820 cached Mem

  PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND     
 2339 root      20   0   76868   3696   2652 R  99.8  0.0  55:52.53 cupsd       
   10 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   1.3  0.0   0:19.72 rcuos/2     
 2519 root      20   0  666088  22280  13220 S   1.0  0.2   0:01.31 gnome-term+ 
 1172 root      20   0  487632  51176  39124 S   0.7  0.4   0:05.67 Xorg        
 1971 root      20   0  286792   5032   3952 S   0.7  0.0   0:00.08 indicator-+ 
    7 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.3  0.0   0:04.42 rcu_sched
```

(the origin question is about java topic, as i cannot post a new question in stackoverflow, i just reedit the old one)

Comment: you need to flood fill the surroundings of the house and detect walls that are attached to the flooded area (see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8070401/android-flood-fill-algorithm)

Comment: you can construct the [dual graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dual_graph) and recover all the dual edges outgoing the dual node that represents the outside space.