# Converting recursive to iterative function (Revealing tiles)

Tags: c, recursion, iteration

I know there are a lot of similar questions, but I can't figure out how to translate the generic examples to my specific case.

I have a recursive `reveal_tiles` function that is supposed to mark all the adjacent cells in a `H*W` matrix with no items in them as revealed. For example:

```
...###......  ->  ...###......
..#---##....  ->  ..#   ##....
..#----#....  ->  ..#    #....
.#------###.  ->  .#      ###.
.#---@----#.  ->  .#   @    #.
.#-------#..  ->  .#       #..
..#-----#...  ->  ..#     #...
...#####....  ->  ...#####....
```

Where `#` means that there is an item in that tile, `-` are the tiles we want to reveal and `@` is the position where we start revealing.

This is the pseudo-code I used for revealing all the empty tiles:

```c
static void reveal_tiles(int y, int x) {
    /* Not a '#' */
    if (!has_item(y, x)) {
        grid[y][x] = FLAG_REVEALED;

        const int start_y = (y > 0)     ? y - 1 : y;
        const int start_x = (x > 0)     ? x - 1 : x;
        const int end_y   = (y < H - 1) ? y + 1 : y;
        const int end_x   = (x < W - 1) ? x + 1 : x;

        /* ---
         * -@-
         * --- */
        for (int cur_y = start_y; cur_y <= end_y; cur_y++)
            for (int cur_x = start_x; cur_x <= end_x; cur_x++)
                if (grid[cur_y][cur_x] != FLAG_REVEALED)
                    reveal_tiles(cur_y, cur_x);
    }
}
```

The problem is that when I have a lot of adjacent empty tiles, the function calls itself too many times and a stack overflow occurs.

What's the best way of converting this recursive function to its iterative version?

Comment: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/flood-fill-algorithm/ take this as a hint.

Comment: Possible answers (or hints) here: [a working non-recursive floodfill algorithm written in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1257117/a-working-non-recursive-floodfill-algorithm-written-in-c)

Comment: That's the term I was looking for: Flood-fill. Now I can probably find something useful.

Comment: why static in your example. And the example only replaces `-` with ` `. Can you provide a better example

Comment: @0___________ The function is static because I copied it from my code, does it matter? In my example, I replace dashes with spaces to illustrate what I want to accomplish, while in the code I set the revealed tiles (spaces) as `FLAG_REVEALED`.

Comment: My final solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77269194/11715554